# Closed form solution and combinatorial proof.

Tags: combinatorics

First of all, I would like to figure out a closed form solution for the following summation:

$$\sum^{n}_{k=0} C(n,k)\cdot C(2n,n+k)$$

Where C(n,k) means n choose k, or $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}$

And also demonstrate that this and the closed form solution are equal through a combinatorial proof.

I started by rewriting it into:

$$\sum^{n}_{k=0} C(n,n-k) \cdot C(2n,n-k)$$

But I am not sure if this is actually more helpful, and I am quite stuck.

Comment: It's been fixed now, thank you! It was multiplication

Comment: This is simply ${\large C}_{3n}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{2n}{n+k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{2n}{n-k}=\binom{3n}n$$

by [Vandermonde’s identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity). The link gives a combinatorial proof of Vandermonde’s identity, which you can easily specialize to this particular case of it.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! Accepted.

Comment: @Blessoul: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This one can also be done using complex variables.

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {2n\choose n+k}.$$

Introduce the integral representation
$${2n\choose n+k}
=\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{n+k+1}} \; dz.$$

This gives for the sum the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{n+1}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac{1}{z^k}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{n+1}} 
\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^n
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{2n+1}} 
\left(z+1\right)^n
\; dz
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{3n}}{z^{2n+1}} \; dz.$$

This evaluates to
$${3n\choose 2n} = {3n\choose n}$$
by inspection.